# Hw can I get last inserted id in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to get last inserted id in cake php 3.

if($this->request->is('post')){

```
       $this->loadModel('MyPlaylists');

                    $playlistData = [];
                    $playlistData["user_id"] = $_POST['user_id'];
                    $playlistData["play_list_name"] =  $_POST['play_list_name'];
                    $playlistData["section"] = $_POST['section'];
                    $playlistData["created"] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));
                    $playlistData["status"] = 'active';
                    $playlist_en = $this->MyPlaylists->newEntity();  
                    $this->MyPlaylists->patchEntity($playlist_en, $playlistData);
                    $this->MyPlaylists->save($playlist_en);
                    $id=$this->MyPlaylists->id;
                }
```

I have also tried:

```
$id=$this->MyPlaylists->lastInsertedId;
```

But it is giving error as below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: yes, it is not due to Auto-Tables

Comment: Offtopic: never fiddle with superglobals directly in CakePHP, instead use the abstratcted wrappers to access the data, in this case via the request objects `data()` or `getData()` method: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data

Comment: can you give example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs some fine tuning.

```
$playlist_en    =    $this->MyPlaylists->newEntity();  
$playlist_en    =    $this->MyPlaylists->patchEntity($playlist_en, $playlistData);
$isValid        =    $this->MyPlaylists->save($playlist_en);
if ($isValid) {
    $id    =    $playlist_en->id;
    debug($id); // Check your last insert id
} else {
    pr($playlist_en->errors()); // Check errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a query selecting the first element of the query ordered in DESC. way

```
$newPlaylist = $this->Playlists->find('all',['order' => ['Playlists.id' => 'DESC']])->select(['id']);
```